# Term or idiom to describe a best friend since your childhood

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

In Chinese, there is a four-character phrase, 竹马故友 which could be translated word for word into:

> Bamboo Horse Old Friend: Friends who played together riding toy horses made of bamboo.

I know there is a similar term in Japanese and Korean. Japanese is 竹馬の友 which means a friend of bamboo horse. I heard from a Japanese expert that it is not very common, but not difficult to understand for Japanese.

I wonder how a native speaker of English describes a best friend since childhood. For example, when you introduce him or her, you could say:

> (S)he is my best friend since childhood. We are **[best friend since childhood]** or We used to **[do something]**
>   together.

Is there any suitable term or idiom?

Comment: We usually say *childhood best friend*.

Comment: @Dan Bron: Except that can often refer to someone you haven't interacted with at all in adult life. To avoid ambiguity, *[She **has been** my] best friend **since** childhood* (but personally I'd normally say *...best friend **[ever] since we were children***).

Comment: Just a note: "竹马故友" isn't a Chinese phrase, although it appears in Korean and Japanese. There is however a well-known Chinese phrase "青梅竹马", but it refers to the close relationship a man and a woman (usually they are lovers) have with each other since childhood, instead of childhood good friends.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, I also like "... *since childhood*".

Comment: @Vim Thanks for your comment. As far as I understand, the phrase came form the [Jin Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(265%E2%80%93420)). Maybe it is not broadly used in China. I am not sure. I found the phrase in Chinese Dictionary.

Comment: @Rathony I'm a native speaker, and I've never heard of it before. I just searched an online Chinese dictionary  and found the related phrase 竹马之友 which originates from 《晋书·殷浩传》 ("少时吾与浩共骑竹马，我弃去，浩辄取之。"). Perhaps this is what you intended. It seems that this phrase is quite rarely used in Chinese as online search returns almost no references that include this use.

Comment: "Brother from another mother"

Comment: Umm..."Diaper Pals"?

Comment: @Dumbledore: that's just a more colorful way to say "childhood best friend", and it shares the same problem of not really saying anything about the current day: it could, and often does, mean someone who you were inseparable from all the way through middle school, and then one of you moved and you haven't seen each other since.

Comment: @Marthaª Fair Statement!!

Comment: Please be clear: that any Chinese phrase could be translated word-for-word into Bamboo Horse Old Friend doesn’t mean that must come into English as “Friends who played together riding toy horses made of bamboo.” If you accept that is one of several possible translations, fine. Otherwise, what’s the point?

You yourself said “a friend of bamboo horse” which might be literal but could never work in English. How should we deal with that, please?

Broadly, no native speaker of English describes a best friend since childhood. There is no such idiom.

Is that clear, or not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***"Lifelong friends"*** is about as far back as you can go because most people would understand that tiny babies don't really have "friends" so to say "lifelong", it's generally understood that as long as someone were capable of having/being a friend, they've been friends.

Comment: I *do* have a friend that I’ve been “friends” with longer than I can remember, since our mothers would stick us in a shared playpen as infants. He hit me with a rattle once, I'm told, and my mother assured his that I probably deserved it. :P

Comment: @KRyan Time for a little payback ;)

Answer (score 5):

I am not a native speaker, but I've come across [***bosom friends***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bosom+friend) to signify a thick friendship between people. Also ***bosom buddy.***

> One's close or closest friend; a friend one holds dear to one's heart

[The Free Dictionary]

**Usage:**

> We have been ***bosom friends*** since we were toddlers.

Comment: "Bosom buddy: informal: A very close or intimate friend: [e.g.]
'it’s clear that Jeff and Tom are bosom buddies from way back'" from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bosom-buddy

Comment: *Bosom buddy* is the idiomatic form of the phrase, thanks to the alliteration. Also somewhat archaic.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy. Your answer is good. But, the expressions "bosom friends" and "bosom buddy" refer to the closeness of relationship between two or more persons as friends; the expressions do not refer to the time from when such relationship subsisted. I think the crux of the instant question is not the closeness of the relationship, but the duration of the time from when such relationship subsisted.

Answer (score 3):

A common phrase for someone you were friends with *in* childhood is **childhood best friend**

However, that can often refer to someone you haven't seen since you left school. If it's someone you're still friends with, an unambiguous phrase that is commonly used is **we've been best friends since childhood**.

Note the tense used in the second example. "*Best friend since childhood*" doesn't work as a noun-phrase, the noun-phrase is "*best friend*". Hence you can say "we've been *best friends* since childhood", meaning "we were *best friends* when we were children and we still are". You can't say "We are *best friends since childhood*", or "She is my *best friend since childhood*".

---

*Shamelessly cobbled together from comments, because it's exactly what I was thinking and after nearly 24 hours no-one else has made it into an answer*

Comment: Although it has to be said that the OP himself uses that exact phrase in the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks for the comment. I've now edited to clarify where the OP was going wrong in his usage of the phrase.

Comment: Well spotted, I hadn't noticed the present tense used. Sorry, but I can't upvote twice :)

Comment: @AndyT Amazing. That part I haven't noticed at all.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best answer could be:

> ... are/ were (depending on the situation) **friends forever**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. Thank you for pointing out the silly mistake that I had inadvertently commited.

Comment: You're welcome, typos happen to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that 竹馬故友is not Chinese at all, for friends since childhood, Chinese use 青梅竹马as idiom for a boy and a girl. with some hint of future marriage. for boys. there's no idiom, rather aslang, 光屁股一起长大的哥们，literally means
a buddy from age of bare bottoms