# "Duration of the time" or "duration"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, word-usage

I am not sure whether or not we can, for "duration of the time", write just "duration".

Here is the text which I encountered the problem in writing:

> The expressions "bosom friends" and "bosom buddy" refer to the closeness of relationship between two or more persons as friends; the expressions do not refer to the time from when such relationship subsisted. I think the crux of the question is not the closeness of the relationship, but the **duration of the time** during which such relationship subsisted.

Reference: see my comment to the answer of BiscuitBoy to the question entitled "Term or idiom to describe a best friend since your childhood". Link: [Term or idiom to describe a best friend since your childhood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309492/term-or-idiom-to-describe-a-best-friend-since-your-childhood)

My question is: could I have written just "duration" for "duration of the time"?

Comment: Your question received one close vote for proof-reading. I don't agree with it, but I think at least you need to include your own research efforts.

Comment: You need to link the answer. Nobody will be able to find it.

Comment: "the duration of the time from when such relationship subsisted." seems very poorly written to me.  In fact the piece as a whole is full of grammatical errors.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I have edited the question and included the reference therein.

Comment: You should include the link. And I would say, [*the length of time*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/length)... or ...*it depends on how long/old the friendship is...*

Comment: @Mari-LouA.  I have edited the question and given the reference in the question itself. I do not know how a link is included. If possible, kindly help me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I fail to comprehend how "Here is ..." is a format for quoting the text I read somewhere and not for the text I wrote somewhere and, more so, when the format ("Here is ...") contained words like "in writing". Kindly elaborate, if possible.

Comment: @MaxWilliams. Thank you for your comment. I have modified the line as "I think the crux of the question is not the closeness of the relationship, but the duration of the time during which such relationship subsisted" and thus substituted "during which" for "from when". You have said "... the piece as a whole is full of grammatical errors". Kindly point out the errors, if possible.

Comment: Clarification: *Here is the text which I encountered the problem in writing:* is unclear, ambiguous, and awkward sounding. Trust me, it is. Instead,  substitute the first two sentences with something like: *The following text is a comment I left beneath BiscuitBoy's answer. Did I use the expression "duration of the time" correctly?* The link to your original comment is posted in an earlier comment. Hope this helps.

Comment: The phrase *the duration of the time* is a bit unusual. But had I come across it in a hundred-year-old book it wouldn't have surprised me. In most modern settings it would definitely flag you as a non-native speaker.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes, I am a non-native speaker of English and I am proud to be so.

Comment: Did my comment seem to be an insult somehow?

Comment: @shawnt00 Does it seem that I said that?

Comment: Mentioning that you are proud suggested you might have thought I called that into question. I wasn't sure why you brought it up so I figured I should ask.

Comment: @shawnt00 Understood. But tell me how it was relevant for you that I am a non-native speaker. How comes the question of flagging me as a non-native speaker. There is perhaps no such flag.

Comment: Presumably native fluency is the ultimate goal for a language learner. I simply meant that nobody would say it that way in normal conversation (though maybe in something very poetic) and while people will understand it it will stand out as unusual.

Comment: @shawnt00 That could stand out as "unusual". But, where is the scope at this site to flag me as a non-native speaker?

Comment: If you took some offense then my apology. 1) It's pretty much given that questions on this site are from non-native speakers. 2) My usage of the word *you* in the original comment was really intended as a "generic you" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you) not directed to you personally and with the intention of helping. No insult was intended. I think perhaps the heart of your confusion is a misunderstanding of the verb *flag* which has nothing to do with your account here.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thank you! The only issue was your sentence "...would definitely flag you as a non-native speaker". The sentence sounded as if it was wrongful to be a non-native speaker. However, the issue is now resolved. Thank you once again!

Comment: Actually I've just realized that part of the confusion is that I thought this was an ELL question and it wasn't. Glad it got sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can just replace

> duration of the time during which such relationship subsisted

with

> longevity.

In this context, [longevity (as per Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longevity) means:

> the length of time that something or someone lasts or continues